# Several modular includes vs unified or combined includes

Tags: php, optimization

This has been a long-standing concern for me. Take Wordpress, which with each page view includes about 70 to 100 different files. I understand that caching does happen on various levels in the server, but the 80s super-efficient coding side of me reels everytime I think of having a web application needing to load several tiny files to do something as simple and outputting a bit of HTML.

Some of the trade-offs I recognize:

Several files:

- Load only what you need
- Potentially less memory needed to store functions/classes
- Easier to manage a large project

Unified files:

- No bootloader logic needed
- Run an application from a handful of files
- Potentially less file accesses needed

Obviously, the complexity of the application matters. In a small application, getting away with a functions.php file and a classes.php file works fine. And on the other side, due to the complexity of Wordpress, in order to have the modular functionality, the several files makes sense.

That being said, I have created custom Wordpress front-ends intended for high-traffic web sites which are 100% custom coded and simply use the Wordpress database to deliver the content. The speed difference is insanely better, but the website owner is limited to only using plugins for the admin area.

So, the question is really, how much of an impact do the "many file modular includes" type frameworks have on performance/a server?

Is it worth worrying about for general websites that are not mission critical and high-demand?

Comment: What people usually do to optimize wp is slap a cache engine on it and that'll fix 98% of the usual performance issues. It's not a bad approach and you definitely want to do some caching even with optimized code when the content you serve doesn't update every second.

Comment: This question is not about Wordpress optimization, rather I'm using Wordpress as an example of a complex system that fits well breaking everything out in to separate files.